# Problemas con el plugin bootstrap-show-password y el evento keyup

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con el plugin bootstrap-show-password.
Intento hacer un control de tamaño máximo de contraseña en un KeyUp para sacar un aviso justo al completar el tamaño máximo y no me funciona cuando he pulsado sobre el "botón ojo" para ver la contraseña. En este modo en que se puede ver la contraseña no se dispara el evento keyup. Lo he asociado a una clase pero tampoco funciona si lo asocio a un id. Tampoco parece hacer caso al maxlength=16 en este modo. ¿alguna idea?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
</head>

<body>
  
    <div id="enterPass" class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Contraseña</label>
            <input id="passwd" type="password" name="passwd"  maxlength=16 class="form-control control-Longitud"  data-toggle="password"  data-placement="after" required/>
   <div id="passwdHelp"  style="visibility:hidden;" class="form-text text-muted helpCampo">Máximo permitido 16 carácteres</div>
          </div>
    
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-show-password/1.0.3/bootstrap-show-password.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    $(function() {
 
  var max_long_password=16;
  
      $('#password').password();
   
   $('.control-Longitud').keyup(function(){
        
        var chars = $(this).val().length;
        var diff = max_long_password - chars;
        if (diff==0){
  
          $("#passwdHelp").css("visibility", "visible");
        }
        else{

            $("#passwdHelp").css("visibility", "hidden");
           }
  });
   
   
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: aqui lo tienes: http://jsfiddle.net/2a07nqbf/2/

Comment: solo debias poner en tu input del password : onkeyup="miFuncion();"

Comment: con eso llamas a la funcion que debe controlar el max-length del password y lsto

Comment: !Pero si eso no funciona!. Esto no es una solución tiene el mismo fallo que mi código. Ejecuto lo que has dejado jsfiddle.net , pulso en el ojo a continuación y ahora continuo pudiendo escribir en el campo sin control de longitud.

Comment: claro el problema tuyo era que no mostraba el mensaje a los 16 digitos.. ahora lo hace.. ahora debes buscar una opcion que te permita establecer el maxlength ..

Comment: puedes usar maxlength="16" en tu input

Comment: Mi programa si mostraba el mensaje a los 16 digitos el problema es que no lo muestra cuando has pulsado en boton del ojo para tener la password visible y entonces comienzas a escribir. En tu ejemplo pasa lo mismo. Ese es mi problema.